# How to format output of a user account from /etc/passwd

Tags: linux, bash

I want to format output of a user account from `/etc/passwd` to display only the name, role, and directory path, all separated by commas. I know this should be easy, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to display between certain colons. (Note this should work with any username, not just the ex)

Ex of `grep joe /etc/passwd`:

```
joe:x:1001:1001:System Admin:/home/joe:/bin/bash
```

**Desired Output**:

```
joe, System Admin, /home/joe
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does it have to be bash? Generally, `awk` command is used for such manipulations, but string manipulation is must more simple in `ruby` for example. You can run `ruby` also from command line, I can send you solution in ruby if you want.

Answer (score 5):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=":"; OFS=", " } $1=="joe" { print $1,$5,$6; exit }' /etc/passwd
```

(but you should show a little more effort next time -- your question is very downvotable :))

Answer (score 4):

With `cut` using comma as `--output-delimiter`:

```
cut -d: -f1,5,6 --output-delimiter=, /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
grep joe /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1,5,6
```

If you **really** need "," as a delimiter:

```
grep "^joe:" /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1,5,6 | tr : ,
```

The "^" ensures only matches to "joe" at the beginning of the line are intercepted (Thanks PSkocik for the reminder). `grep` by defaults accepts a `regex`.

Translation in bash, but two lines:

```
x=`grep joe /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1,5,6`
echo ${x/:/,}
```

Comment: That worked great.  If you don't mind me asking, how does this work?  Guessing it has something to do with cutting the 1st, 5th and 6th content between colons?

Comment: Given that both versions result in three processes, I'd prefer the pure-POSIX version. BTW, you should grep for `^joe:`, not `joe`.

Comment: @Eric The `cut` commands reads in a file line by line, cutting at the delimiter `-d` and outputting only the field `-f`. When you use piping - `|` - which is something you **must** acquaint yourself with, the 'file' is actually `stdin`, which is "piped" to from the previous command -`grep` - receiving as "file" the `stdout` from `grep. The second pipe to tr translates ":" to "," in each line in a similar fashion.

Comment: @kabanus The : should be there too. `^joe` will match all usersnames starting with `joe` (e.g., joey or joeblow)

Comment: @PSkocik Your pedantic, I like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it purely in shell (POSIX sh is enough, Bash not needed), then [`read`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) is your friend:

```
while IFS=: read user pw uid gid gecos home shell ; do 
    if [ "$user" = "joe" ] ; then 
        echo "$user, $gecos, $home" 
    fi 
done < /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Slight variation: `grep joe /etc/passwd | while IFS=: read -r u x uid gid n h s; do echo "$u, $n, $h"; done`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, I'd go with `grep '^joe:'` just for general strictness

Comment: Agreed, no need not to anchor and terminate. I like you answer. I took your advise and updated mine `:p`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the variations, in bash itself, you can pipe the output of `grep` directly to a brace enclosed `read` and separate the fields using `IFS` as required. Using short names for the fields, you could do:

```
grep '^joe:' /etc/passwd | 
{ IFS=: read -r u x uid gid n h s; echo "$u, $n, $h"; }
```

Which would give the output you seek (if `/etc/passwd` contained the entry)